# No module named dbindexes

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, autoload

My goal is to enable SQL features with non-SQL database. My app is deployed on Google Appengine. I have set up my django project with dbindexer lib and autoload lib according the instructions at http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/09/Get-SQL-features-on-NoSQL-with-django-dbindexer.
However, when it is run on dev_appserver, an exception occurs: "Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named dbindexes". Why is this?
My project setup:

- blogapp

  - models.py
  - ...
  - dbindexes.py
- galleryapp

  - models.py
  - ...
  - dbindexes.py
- dbindexes.py
- settings.py

This is an excerpt of my project settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',
    'djangoappengine',
    'djangotoolbox',
    ...
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'dbindexer',
    'TARGET': 'gae',
},
    'gae': {
        'ENGINE': 'djangoappengine.db',
    },
}

AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'dbindexes'
```

**Notice that all irrelevant part is shown as ellipses (...)**

Thank you

Comment: I had an extra space before _dbindexes.py_

Comment: do you have an __init__.py in your `blogapp` and `galleryapp` folders?